# Haskell: *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse, Parsing, Read File

Tags: parsing, haskell, read-write

I am trying to read values from a .txt file and keep getting the above error. My code reads:

```
file <- readFile "films.txt"
let database = (read file :: [Film])
```

and Film is a data type I declared as:

```
type Film = (String, String, Int)
```

Still quite new to Haskell so have no idea how to parse a string back into the required type. Sort of assumed it would be nice and do it for me like it does with writeFile!

Any hints?

Comment: You can only `read` a string that is in `show` format. Did you show the text to the file first? As it is, there isn't enough in this bug report to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: What Don said: How does the file contents look?

Comment: I used this code to save the films.txt file: 
`saveFile :: [Film] -> IO()`
`saveFile filmList = writeFile "films.txt" (show filmList)`

Comment: Well, then it _should_ be able to be `read` again. Can you edit `films.txt` (assuming it's not too large) into the question, so we can have a look?

Comment: Check the actual file contents, as it might not be what you assume. Did you e.g. by any chance change the definition of `Film` between saving and loading?

Comment: Sure, here is one line of the file films.txt: `[("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982)]`

Comment: Sorry guys! There was nothing wrong with it, for some reason it kept throwing up the exception until i re-saved the file. Can't remember changing any definitions... Thanks anyway!

Comment: If that's _one line_ of `films.txt`, it should be the only (nonempty) one, or the format is not correct.

Comment: Tangential: I recommend that you use a `data` declaration instead of just a tuple synonym.